# How to use AntiXSS but keep output readable?

Tags: .net, security, antixsslibrary

I'm using Microsoft's AntiXSS library to HtmlEncode content being displayed on a web page.

The problem is it encodes more than I want it to.  For example it encodes the colon ":".

Is there a way to HtmlEncode, but not certain characters?

An example is if I have a string like "RE: email subject line", is it possible to use the AntiXSS library to encode that string but have it not show up as "RE&#58; email subject line".  I want the ":" to show up but still want to encode the output.

Update:
The problem was that I was using Razor and the "@" already encodes output.  So by using both the "@" and the AntiXSS Html.Encode call I was double encoding.

Comment: Why would you want it to not encode certain characters? Like the colon.

Comment: By seeking to stop the anti-xss library from doing exactly what it wants to, you are weakening its protection.  It's encoding it for a reason.

Comment: If I have a string like "RE: email subject line", how can I display it on the page like that instead of "RE&#58; email subject line"?

Comment: In what context are you using the output of `HtmlEncode`?

Comment: But in the browser "RE&#58; email subject line" should render just fine as "RE: email subject line". Are you saying it does not?

Comment: View the source and show us what it's doing. Perhaps you have something double encoded. Like "RE&amp;#58; email subject line" which might happen if you take an already-encoded string an encode it again without canonicalizing it first.

Comment: Jason, you are right, I was encoding it twice because I forgot that when using Razor the @ automatically encodes.  I was doing this: @AntiXss.HtmlEncode(myMessage.Subject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing the encoding results on screen as your comments seem to indicate then you are double encoding. &#58; is the colon, and that would be the output of AntiXSS, but something after that is encoding the & to &amp;

What is doing this depends on what you're using. If you're using WebForms then a bunch of the controls will encode Text and other properties by default, and stopping this depends on the control. If you're using MVC the <%: performs encoding of what you're passing before adding it to the output stream. You can either, if you're using MVC3 replace the default encoders ([AntiXSS beta 4.1](http://idunno.org/archive/2011/04/23/antixss-4-1-beta-1.aspx), or [roll your own](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx) if you don't want to use a beta), or tell MVC you're outputting an already encoding string by outputting an [HtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx).

In [.NET 4.5](http://idunno.org/archive/2011/09/14/net-4-5-now-includes-the-core-antixss-functions.aspx) the core parts of AntiXSS will be built in and configurable via a config switch.

Comment: Yes, this is what happened.  I am using Razor and the @ syntax already encodes output.  So when I did something like @AntiXss.HtmlEncode(myMessage.Subject) it was double encoding.